# Updating the background of a hidden Windows Forms control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have a Windows Forms control (a subclass of `Panel`) that serves as a panel that displays an image.  The background of the control serves as the image that is displayed to the user.
The image itself is generally a screenshot of whatever is behind the application.  The method of obtaining this screenshot is to hide the application and have the user press a button.
When that button is pressed, the screenshot is saved as the background of the Windows Forms control, and then the application is shown again.  The background doesn't appear to update
until the control is visible again, and this causes a noticeable flicker of sorts as the old background switches to the new background.  Is there a way to cause the background to 
change while the control is hidden and remove this flicker?

Code:

```
public void updateBackground()
{
    Image bg = null;

    do
    {
        // this just gets the background using gdi32 and user32 calls
        bg = Utilities.getDesktopImage(); 
    }
    while (bg == null);

    // this function invokes the GUI thread to change the BackgroundImage of the 
    //    drawPanel
    drawPanel.setBackground(bg)

    // drawPanel is a child control to the main Form
    mainForm.show();
}
```

I have also tried using various forms of `Refresh()` and `Invalidate()` to get the control to update before it is shown.  `Application.DoEvents()` *seems* to improve the speed, but there is still a noticible change from the old background to the new one.

Is there something that I'm missing?  I can't seem to find what I'm looking for on Google, or elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Thanks.

Comment: It is pretty unclear how the old background can be visible at all.  You call the Show() method *after* setting the background.  The Opacity property is otherwise is cheap way to hide transitions.

Comment: @HansPassant that's the primary thing I'm trying to figure out... it doesn't make too much sense to me, either.  What do you suggest doing with the Opacity property?  Would I set the Opacity to 0, show the form, and then set the Opacity to 100 again?

Comment: Right.  Except set it back to 99 or you'll still get flicker.  And call the form's Update() method before that.

Comment: That doesn't seem to alleviate the issue, and causes other controls to turn black for about a second.  The order I am trying it in goes opacity = 0, update, show, opacity = 99

Comment: @red_sky `this function invokes the GUI thread to change the BackgroundImage` - while it is possible for this same thread to act on  our UI, it sounds like you know that's NOT a good thing to do--UI is not threadsafe. So can you show us a bit more of the threading code? I want to see if how your marshaling. The other question is why a panel? does an picturebox make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your logic to another thread (Task, Backgroundworker or ThreadPool). This shall remove the lag you see.

The flicker occurs because (I assume) you do some relatively lengthy work in the UI thread, which blocks graphic message loop and everything "freeze" for a fraction of a second.

Comment: I don't think that will solve the problem.  The delay before the new image replaces the old image is the same across every machine I've tried it on, and stepping through the code (which gives processes more time to complete) doesn't change the delay at all.  The form itself doesn't freeze (the controls, on the GUI thread, are still clickable) it just has a delay before the image switches.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Win7 or Vista and is the Desktop Window Manager Service running?

Does the problem go away when the DWM is disabled (Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Services --> Desktop Window Manager Session Manager)?

It sounds like an issue with Aero - the way the DWM works is that the form's graphics buffer is not updated while it is hidden.  The DWM stores the data from the last visible paint and doesn't refresh until the form is visible again.  This causes the previous form canvas to be visible briefly until Windows gets around to repainting the changes since it was last visible (ie: the flicker).

This article discusses some of the topics :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2006/05/02/588934.aspx

There is probably a way to override some of this behaviour but I'm not familiar with it off the top of my head.  Tagging this with GDI+ may help get better answers.

Comment: The issue appears both on Windows XP and Windows 7 (I don't have any Vista development machines).  I have added the GDI+ tag, thanks for the suggestion.  Thanks for the feedback, and I'll go ahead and try what you suggested on Windows 7 in any event (it can't hurt).

Comment: I'm actually curious what it is you are trying to do - are you displaying the entire background scaled to a panel or are you just trying to "punch a hole" through your form to see what is behind it?  There may be an easier way to do this...

Comment: I'm displaying the entire background scaled to a panel, but "punching a hole" is what it should feel like to the user.  There is some networking involved, as it's a collaborative image manipulation-type program.  I feel like "punching a hole" would make the collaborative aspect really difficult to implement.

Comment: So something like adding SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True) to the parent form's constructor would not be a viable option - using TransparencyKey?  Do you need to retain the image to process or is it just for UI effect?  If the latter, it may be easier to use Form Transparency to get the visual effect (in the first instance) and then take the screenshot without needing to hide and show the form again - normal double buffering could then do the swap from transparency to background image...depending on how fast you want to do this and how low level you want to go.

Comment: The image needs to be retained for processing of the image.  The image also needs to be drawn on, which a "canvas" image is used for.  It would add a good bit of complexity if the background were made transparent, drawings were taken independently of the image, and then merged at some point(s) throughout the process.  In the current implementation, the drawing uses System.Drawing.  Talk has been made to go to DirectX, as it's faster and allows more control, but that would be a large undertaking right now.

Comment: DirectX is probably the most professional way to go.  If you want a cheap hack, however, I think that abusing form transparency can probably work.  If you add transparency support as above you can "disable" it on the fly by setting TransparencyKey to Color.Transparent - with a borderless form this would allow you to make the form "invisible" for a moment by setting TransparencyKey to, say, Color.Green and showing a green panel docked to the foreground of your parent form - this gets rid of flicker since the native double buffer isn't crapped by having to hide and show the main form.

Comment: sorry, meant to say you can disable transparency by setting TransparencyKey = Nothing

Comment: So, I should have the transparency key set to nothing by default, but when I want to show the form and change the panel's image, I should set the transparency key to whatever the panel's background color is, show the form, and then change the transparency key back to nothing?

Comment: Sort of, yes.  Setting the transparency key to whatever colour will "punch out" any visible parts of the form which are that color.  If you set the key to green, then make visible a borderless green panel which completely covers the foreground of your form (eg: docked to fill the form) then your form will essentially disappear - it will still be active, in the foreground, and processing OnPaint events, however, and its DWM buffer will be kept alive.  This might help with flicker issues - you can then change the form background and hide the green (ie:transparent) panel to "show" the form again.

Comment: Note that this will only work if your form has no border (ie no frame - FormBorderStyle = none).  Otherwise your form will be transparent but will still have a frame, [-][O][X] buttons, etc.

Comment: Using this method makes the controls on my panel with the image disappear.  They are still clickable, they just aren't visible any longer.  The background color of the form is yellow, and that's all that appears.

Comment: You have to call SetStyle as above in the base form's constructor or else it won't work - it must also be set in any child forms within the main form.

Comment: Also, it seems this won't work if your main form is an MDI container... there may be a way around this, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'll verify that the child form has the required style set in it's constructor.  Thanks